# Reference to generic type when returning view that uses a protocol

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am being unable to return a View that uses a protocol as a dependency as this is throwing me `Reference to generic type 'LoginView' requires arguments in <...>`.

```
func makeLoginView(viewModel: LoginViewModelType) -> LoginView {
    return LoginView(viewModel: viewModel)
}
```

My LoginView uses LoginViewModelType as I have two different view models.

```
protocol LoginViewModelType: ObservableObject {
    var bookingPaymentViewModel: BookingPaymentViewModel? { get }

    var email: String { get set }
    var password: String { get set }\
    ...

    func login()
}

struct LoginView<ViewModel: LoginViewModelType>: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
```

I can't understand what I am doing wrong, the LoginView should be able to return a View regardless as it complies to LoginViewModelType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to constrain `makeLoginView` to accept a generic of type `LoginViewModelType` and then use that same generic in the returned value.

```
class BookingPaymentViewModel { }

func makeLoginView<T:LoginViewModelType>(viewModel: T) -> LoginView<T> {
    return LoginView(viewModel: viewModel)
}

protocol LoginViewModelType: ObservableObject {
    var bookingPaymentViewModel: BookingPaymentViewModel? { get }

    var email: String { get set }
    var password: String { get set }

    func login()
}

struct LoginView<ViewModel: LoginViewModelType>: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("test")
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. I have been wondering what I have been doing wrong and I have never had issues with this before. I imagined I had to constrain it but I had no idea how, specially considering it's my first time using SwiftUI/Combine.

Comment: Sure. Generics are tricky -- luckily, the concepts apply across Swift and not just to SwiftUI/Combine.